# Recommended pattern for 'include guards' in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

We are all familiar with:

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER_FILE_H
#define MY_HEADER_FILE_H
...
#endif
```

Until recently, I have never worried about loading the same Scheme file twice (The SICP Scheme interpreter implementation changes that ...)

Is there a recommended pattern in Scheme to emulate 'include guards'? Can it be portable, or is it most likely implementation specific?

I am currently using the `scm` implementation, and I have come up with this so far:

```
(if (not (defined? my-file-included)) 
  (begin
    (define my-file-included #f)
...

)) ; include guard
```

So I have started pasting this pattern around all my files, but I can't say I like this very much. Besides, `defined?` is a keyword in `scm` and its argument is not evaluated: `(defined? my-var)` while it seems to be a normal function in `guile`: `(defined? 'my-var)` and `mit-scheme` won't have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a macro to detect if the given identifier is bound or no not using `syntax-case`. See: http://saito.hatenablog.jp/entry/2012/09/14/010849 (it's written in Japanese but you can copy&paste the code.) Even though it uses only R6RS procedures and macros, it may not work on some implementations. (The comment of the blog post mentioning R6RS Chapter 10 Expression process.)

If you are using one of R6RS or R7RS implementations (say Guile compliant R6RS), it is better to make your including file as a library and use `import`.

If you want to do something like this:

```
#if __GUILE__
# include "foo.incl"
#else
# include "bar.incl"
#endif
```

then you can use `cond-expand` like this:

```
(cond-expand
  (guile ...)
  (else ...))
```

NB: `cond-expand` is defined in R7RS and SRFI-0.

Comment: Thanks v much Takashi, i will look at this carefully